# How to specify the order of the shapes in the diagram

Tags: javascript, svg, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-dataviz

Just wondering if there is a way to specify the sequence of the shapes in the kendo diagram when I add shapes to the diagram via datasource and connectionSource.

the example 1 is

http://dojo.telerik.com/aQUPE

I am trying to get the s1 above the s2 and s2 above s3, but the result is s3 above s2 and s2 above s1.

the example 2 is

http://dojo.telerik.com/EfUPu

I am still trying to add s1 above s2 and s2 above s3. In the next level , I am trying to have s4 above s5

Please could  you let me how specify the order of the space in the diagram if it can be done? I am using layout - layered and right.

If not, could you let me know the logic of setting up the shapes' positions behide the diagram

Thanks very much
Regards

Comment: It looks like the shapes are positioned in "inverse" order: the first one will go at the bottom, the last one will be on top. If you invert the order of `testConnection` they appear in the positions that you want.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Thanks. Please take a look at the second example, the order of the dataSource is s1,s2,s3,s4,s5. the the result is just like random output

Comment: if you order it s5,s4,s3,s2,s1 it works fine (at least it does for me): http://dojo.telerik.com/EfUPu/5

Answer (score 0):

Update,

Since I use the layer type as "Layered", there is NO way to set the order of the shape in this case.

However, there is a way to work around, which just to set the layer type to "tree"